# Get the names of directories and the number of files in each directory using a Batch file

Tags: batch-file

I'm rather new to the use of batch files and the codes involved. What I would like to do is get both a list of directories/sub-directories and get the number of specific files (.txt, .MP4, etc.) in each directory, and then store both in a .txt file. I've already figured out how to get a list of directories and store them:

```
dir /b /ad "C:\FILE" > "C:\List.txt"
```

Now how would I get the number of files in each directory? I would prefer the format in the text file to be something like:

**"folder1 - 5 files"**
**"folder2 - 3 files"**

Folder name and the number of files in a line, then the next folder. Thank you for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 1):

Next script might work as expected. Some basic explanation given using `rem` comments.

```
@ECHO OFF >NUL
SETLOCAL enableextensions

    rem set up initial folder
set "myFolder=C:\FILE"

    rem set up extension list (no * or ? wildcards, please)
    rem could be defined explicitly as follows
set "myExtens=bat html"
    rem or, with next  proposed usage: 28786418.bat "bat html"
set "myExtens=%~1"
    rem or, with next (current) usage: 28786418.bat bat html
set "myExtens=%*"

    rem call a subroutine to output folder name & file count 
call :filecount "%myFolder%"

    rem call that subroutine for ech subfolder (cf. /A:D /S switch)
for /F "tokens=*" %%g in ('
    DIR /B /A:D /S "%myFolder%"
  ') do call :filecount "%%~g"

ENDLOCAL
goto :eof

:filecount
    rem subroutine
    rem input: (full) path to folder
    rem output: echo "input" - file count

    rem init a file counter to zero 
set /A "numFiles=0"
    rem increment file counter by 1 for each file in folder
    rem note '2^>nul' to avoid "file not found" message if folder empty
    rem note 'set' does not require delayed variable expansion
    rem            as the 'numFiles' variable correctly increments
for /F "tokens=*" %%G in ('
    DIR /B /A:-D "%~1" 2^>nul
  ') do (
         rem treat the extension list if any
         rem ( or insert here any other logic instead ) 
      if defined myExtens (
        for %%H in (%myExtens%) do if /i ".%%~H"=="%%~xG" set /A "numFiles+=1"
      ) else (
        set /A "numFiles+=1"
      )
    )
    rem display output to console (command line window)
echo "%~1" - %numFiles%
goto :eof
```

To store output to a text file, you could use (suppose the script is saved as `28786418.bat`)

```
 28786418.bat>list.txt
```

**Edit (a supplement)**: output with `set "myFolder=d:\bat\StackOverflow"`

```
==>D:\bat\StackOverflow\28786418.bat
"d:\bat\StackOverflow" - 44
"d:\bat\StackOverflow\files" - 27
"d:\bat\StackOverflow\files\backup_done" - 0
"d:\bat\StackOverflow\files\Roboto" - 0
"d:\bat\StackOverflow\files\root" - 0
"d:\bat\StackOverflow\files\Roboto\backup_done" - 0
"d:\bat\StackOverflow\files\root\Ian-ionescu" - 2
"d:\bat\StackOverflow\files\root\John-doe" - 2
"d:\bat\StackOverflow\files\root\Nicola-sheperd" - 1
"d:\bat\StackOverflow\files\root\Sara-smith" - 2

==>D:\bat\StackOverflow\28786418.bat bat html>files\28786418.txt

==>type files\28786418.txt
"d:\bat\StackOverflow" - 40
"d:\bat\StackOverflow\files" - 3
"d:\bat\StackOverflow\files\backup_done" - 0
"d:\bat\StackOverflow\files\Roboto" - 0
"d:\bat\StackOverflow\files\root" - 0
"d:\bat\StackOverflow\files\Roboto\backup_done" - 0
"d:\bat\StackOverflow\files\root\Ian-ionescu" - 0
"d:\bat\StackOverflow\files\root\John-doe" - 0
"d:\bat\StackOverflow\files\root\Nicola-sheperd" - 0
"d:\bat\StackOverflow\files\root\Sara-smith" - 0

==>
```

Comment: This does work, but it is adding 1 additional file when there isn't an additional one. I'm guessing its counting the file folder. Where in the code would I have it to only count based on the extension?